# Error while pushing data into nested array of mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to push data in the treatment arrray which is nested in files array.

schema of patient:

var treatmentSchema = new Schema({

```
prescription:{
    type : String,
},
record: {
    data: Buffer, 
    contentType: String
}
```

});

var FileSchema = new Schema({

```
drName : {
    type : String,
    requried : true
},
desease :{
    type:String,
    requried:true
},
treatment : [treatmentSchema]
```

},{
timestamps : true
});

var patientSchema = new Schema({

```
pat_no:{
    type:Number
},
username:{
    type : String,
    requried : true,
    unique : true
},
DOB : {
    type:Date 
}
,
 password:{
    type : String,
    requried : true,
    unique : true
},
name : {
    type : String,
    requried : true
},
email:{
    type : String,
    requried : true
},
aadhar : {
    type : String,
    requried : true,
    unique : true
},
image: {
    data: Buffer, 
    contentType: String
},
nomeneeAadhar:{
    type : String,
    requried : true,
},
files : [FileSchema]
```

};

code:

Doctor.findById(req.cookies.user)
.then((doctor)=>{

```
              var image={}
              if(req.files)
              {
                image={
                   data: new Buffer(req.files.record.data,'base64'),
                   ctType: req.files.record.name.split('.').pop()
                  }
              }
             Patient.updateOne({"_id" :req.params.patID },
             {
                  "$push": {
                        "files.$[t].treatment":{
                           "prescription":req.body.comment,
                           "record":image
                          }
                        }
            },
           { arrayFilters: [ { "t.drname": doctor.name ,  "t.desease":req.body.dise } ]},
                  
   function(err, result){
      if(err){
           console.log(err)
      }else if(!result){
           //update not success
           console.log("no success")
      }else{
           console.log(result)
           console.log("success")

      }
  })
   .then((doc)=>{
        res.send(doc)
   })
})
```

result:
{"n":1,"nModified":0,"ok":1}

I tried this method as well:

Doctor.findById(req.cookies.user)
.then((doctor)=>{

```
              var image={}
              if(req.files)
              {
                image={
                   data: new Buffer(req.files.record.data,'base64'),
                   ctType: req.files.record.name.split('.').pop()
                  }
              }
          Patient.updateOne(
                  {
                      _id:req.params.id,
                      "files.drName" :doctor.name,
                      "files.desease" :req.body.dise
                  },
                  {
                      $push :{
                                  "files.$.treatment":{
                                       "prescription":req.body.comment,
                                       "record":image
                                  }
                             }
                  }
            )
            .then((doc)=>{
              res.send(doc)
            })
})
```

DB connection:

var connect = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/doctor', {

```
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then((db) => {
    console.log("Database Connected Successfully");
})
.catch((err) => {
    var err = new Error("Error in Database connectivity");
    return next(err);
})
```

Data not get updated in db.
please help!!
thank you!

Comment: Format your schemas/Code pointers properly.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: Can you show the code where you connect to the DB?

Comment: I added the connection part. You can see now.